# "XML Parsing Error: no root element found" when editing a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, collectives

When editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15777492/4751173), I get an error in my browser console:

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found
> Location: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/shared/get-communities-by-tags?tags=powershell&tags=teamcity&tags=exit-code&_=1630781643204
> Line Number 1, Column 1:

Browser: Firefox 91.0.2 on macOS Big Sur 11.5.2. The bug occurs whether I'm logged in or not. The link in the Location produces an empty page, so it's not surprised it can't be parsed as XML.

[image]

Comment: I glanced at the question title and was just about to "Lost soul" you :D

Comment: My hand also steered towards the "close" button before I who's posting :) `get-communities-by-tags` source does not sound like one of the usual SE source names - do you have any scripts you forgot about running by any chance?

Comment: Nevermind the last part, though - reproduced. Ah, the Collectives feature strikes again!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue. The developers have fixed the issue.